# dustjs iterate through array and get count

Tags: javascript, dust.js, kraken.js

Is there any way in `dustjs` to iterate through array and get the number of occurrence?

I am trying to get the count of type='MOBILE' from the JSON data below:

```
[
    {
        "type": "MOBILE",
        "formattedPhoneNumber": "5123 4566"
    },
    {
        "type": "MOBILE",
        "formattedPhoneNumber": "5123 4568"
    },
    {
        "type": "MOBILE",
        "formattedPhoneNumber": "5123 4568"
    },
    {
        "type": "LANDLINE",
        "formattedPhoneNumber": "5123 4568"
    }
]
```

here I am expecting a count of 3 from above example where type is 'MOBILE'.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple helper to do this for you. A helper transforms data from your context in a specific way. For more information, you can read the documentation on [context helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/)

```
{
  "numbers": [{ "type": "MOBILE", ... }, { ... }],
  "countByKey": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var target = context.resolve(params.target);
    var key = context.resolve(params.key);
    var value = context.resolve(params.value);
    return target.filter(function(item) {
      return item[key] === value;
    }).length;
  }
}
```

Then you can use your helper in a template like this:

```
{#countByKey target=numbers key="type" value="MOBILE"}You have {.} mobile numbers{/countByKey}
```